# The type of get(int) is erroneus

Tags: java, html

Soy nuevo en el foro y no se poner las cosas con codigo y demas, pero tratare de explicar todas las cosas
Codigo JSP

```html
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import = "IDP_web.Herramientas.ListaJefaturas"%> 
<%@ page import = "IDP_web.Herramientas.Consultas"%> 
<%@ page import = "java.util.LinkedList"%> 
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/ii/jefa.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/IDP_web/s">
            <TABLE align="center">
                <TR>
                <tr>
                    <TH>C&oacutedigo de la Jefatura</TH> 
                    <TH>Nombre de la Jefatura</TH> 
                    <TH>Encargado de la jefatura</TH>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                <tr>
                    <td>codigo</td>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>Encargado</td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    LinkedList<ListaJefaturas> lista = Herramientas.Consultas.getJefaturas();
                    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                        out.println("<tr>");
                        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getcodigo() + "</td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getNombre() + "</td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getEncargado() + "</td>");
                        out.println("</tr>");
                    }
                %>
            </table> 

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Codigo donde hago la consulta a la base de datos, Codigo es int, Nombre es varchar y Encargado igual varchar

```
public static LinkedList<ListaJefaturas>  getJefaturas() {
    LinkedList<ListaJefaturas> lista = new LinkedList<ListaJefaturas>();
    try {

        Statement st = connect().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select Codigo,Nombre,Encargado from Jefas");
        while (rs.next()) {
            ListaJefaturas LJ = new ListaJefaturas();
            LJ.setCodigo(rs.getInt("Codigo"));
            LJ.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
            LJ.setEncargado(rs.getString("Encargado"));
            lista.add(LJ);
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        connect().close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Clase con los get y set

```
public class ListaJefaturas {

    private int Codigo;
    private String nombre;
    private String Encargado;

    public int getCodigo() {
        return Codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int Codigo) {
        this.Codigo = Codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getEncargado() {
        return Encargado;
    }

    public void setEncargado(String Encargado) {
        this.Encargado = Encargado;
    }
}
```

El error que muestra es el siguiente [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrias poner tu codigo como codigo y no como imagenes por favor? asi si alguien necesita hacer pruebas se puede copiar el mismo.

Comment: Para poner el codigo en formato de texto has de pegarlo, seleccionarlo y pulsar `ctrl + k` o el icono  `{}`.

Comment: Vale es que de verdad no sabia como hacerlo, voy a tratar de ponerlo

Comment: estas seguro que en tu base de datos dice que el tipo es `int`???

Comment: LinkedList te devuelve un objeto tipo E, has probado a hacer un casting? de este modo: (ListaJefaturas)lista.get(i) y de ahí ya obtener el código, nombre...

Comment: No lo pude solucionar con una LinkedList a si que investigue otro metodo y utilice un ResultSet y listo funciono gracia por su tiempo

Answer (score 0):

En tu JSP se observa que llamas a `getcodigo`, mientras que en tu `ListaJefaturas` lo defines como `getCodigo()`.

Otra cosa que podría estar pasando es que en la clase `ListaJefaturas` tratas de obtener un int de tu base de datos, y normalmente los campos de la base de datos son más grandes, revisa mediante la clase `ResultSetMetadata` el tipo de dato de tu `ResultSet` para esa colmna yo opinaría que es `BigDecimal`.

Adicionalmente es una buena practica desacoplar para trabajar con interfaces en vez de implementaciones, es decir:

```
List<ListaJefaturas> lista = Herramientas.Consultas.getJefaturas();
```

y en `getJefaturas` modificar como

```
List getJefaturas() {
     List lista = new LinkedList();
     try {

        Statement st = connect().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select Codigo,Nombre,Encargado from Jefas");
        while (rs.next()) {
            ListaJefaturas LJ = new ListaJefaturas();
            LJ.setCodigo(rs.getInt("Codigo"));
            LJ.setNombre(rs.getString("Nombre"));
            LJ.setEncargado(rs.getString("Encargado"));
            lista.add(LJ);
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        connect().close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Comment: Ya lo puse como dices, y nada sigue el mismo error, hice una impresion en la pantalla y lo mande al debug para saber que estaba entrando en las variables set y get, efectivamente los datos que solicito si estan entrando y se estan mostrando correctamente